# jQuery getting select options while using $(this)

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to be able to loop through and log each option available in a select dropdown box.  I'm not sure how to do this while using `$(this)`.

This is what I have.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    $(this).find('options').each(function(){
        var boxOpt = $(this).text();
        console.log(boxOpt);
    });
});
```

It currently outputs nothing.  I would like to be able to do something like:
`$(this + ' options').each(function(){...});` but this is not working either.

I have tried
`$(this).find()`, `$(this).children()` and some other variations, but I'm not sure what to do now.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Valid children for a select in HTML are "option", not "options"

Answer (score 4):

`options` should be `option`. You can just add it to the selector string:

```
$('select option').each(function(){
    var boxOpt = $(this).text();

    console.log(boxOpt);
});
```

Comment: For optimisation purposes, that should be `select>option,select>optgroup>option`. But if you were interested in optimisation you wouldn't be using jQuery, so LOL

Comment: Aaahh thank you!  That was driving me crazy.  Unfortunately, I have to use an each statement inside an each statement, so the answer here is semi-correct.  I changed `options` to `option` and it works with .find().  Thank you again

Comment: @ntgCleaner: Why would you need to use a nested `each`?

Comment: @blender I need to do some scripting for each select using each option of that select. I don't like how the current jQuery select styling plugins work, so I am creating my own. So I will need to style each select and option as well as make them work. I may be writing an array for this but I had to work out the basics first

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), l = tags.length, i, opts, m, j;
for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
    opts = tags[i].options;
    m = opts.length;
    for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
        console.log(opts[j].text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, though you'll hate the fact that I only use VJS when it's needed.  Such as for loops when each won't cut it and basic javascript like substring and replace,  etc.   As you said in a comment above, I'm not going for optimisation, but I'm glad you answered this here so I can come back and do it better!